# In PIL, why isn't convert('L') turning image grayscale?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

For a program I'm writing, I need to convert an RGB image to grayscale and read it as a NumPy array using PIL.

But when I run the following code, it converts the image not to grayscale, but to a strange color distortion a bit like the output of a thermal camera, as presented.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Thank you!

http://www.loadthegame.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/thermal-camera.png

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

im = array(Image.open('happygoat.jpg').convert("L"))

inverted = Image.fromarray(im)

imshow(inverted)
show()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

matplotlib's `imshow` is aimed at scientific representation of data - not just image data. By default it's configured to use a high constrast color palette.

You can force it to display data using grayscale by passing the following option:

```
import matplotlib.cm
imshow(inverted, cmap=matplotlib.cm.Greys_r)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this code to view/display an image:

```
from PIL import Image;  
from numpy import *       
from pylab import *    

im = array(Image.open('happygoat.jpg').convert("L"));   

inverted = Image.fromarray(im);    
inverted
```

Comment: Hi can you include some detail as to how this answers the OPs problem? It actually just looks like the exact same code up to the `inverted=...` line.